# Does $p_{1}^x + p_{2}^y = n$ have uniqe solution for $x$ and $y$ ($p_{1}, p_{2}$ are primes).

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

If I'm given a value $n$. And I know its of the form  $p_{1}^x + p_{2}^y$, can I be sure that there is a unique solution for $x$ and $y$ and Can I determine  values of $x$ and $y$, If I know the primes $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ (and $p_{1} \ne p_{2}$)

If yes, how to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From
$$p^x+q^y=p^s+q^t$$
if $(x,y)\neq(s,t)$, we have
$$p^s(p^{x-s}-1)=q^y(q^{t-y}-1)$$

so $p\equiv 1\pmod q$ and $q\equiv 1\pmod p$. This is not possible.

THIS IS WRONG: PLEASE UNACCEPT (sorry for caps, only for visibility)

To find the exponents, if $n$ is not *very* big, the fastest and easiest way is perhaps bruteforcing.

*Remark*: I have assumed that the exponents are positive. If they may be $0$ we have for example
$$2^3+3^2=2^4+3^0$$

Comment: any better idea to find $n$?

Comment: Do you mean $x$ and $y$?

Comment: How about $2^3+3=2+3^2$? The conclusion that $p \equiv 1 \mod{q}$ and $q \equiv 1 \mod{p}$ does not follow

Comment: Not to be unkind, but both the "proof' and the accepted answer here are incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I "thought" it too fast... If OP unaccepts my answer, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to the question is "no". For each of
$$
n \in \{ 11, 35, 133, 259, 2200 \},
$$
we can find distinct primes $p$ and $q$ for which we have
$$
p^a+q^b=p^c+q^d = n
$$
with $(a,b) \neq (c,d)$ and all of $a, b, c$ and $d$ positive integers. Probably this property is not true for other values of $n$, but that does not appear at all easy to prove.

Given $p$ and $q$ and the knowledge that $p^a+q^b=n$ for some integers $a$ and $b$, finding these exponents is certainly polynomial time in $n$.